# ajax send with jquery to php file doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, contacts

I want to send the information of a contact form to the a server and send the contact info as a mail. Just a normal contact form.

But a get a error by jquery.js on line 9631 which is this part:

```
//Do send the request
//This may raise an exception which is actually
//handled in jQuery.ajax (so no try/catch here)
xhr.send( ( options.hasContent && options.data ) || null );
```

Can somebody explain me this error? I don't find the mistake and don't know how to debug it.

```
    <fieldset id="contactForm">
    <p>Wünschen Sie eine Abholung von Schrott oder Edelmetallen<br>
    geben Sie bitte <b>genaue Angaben über die Art und Menge</b> um weitere Rückfragen zu ersparen.
    </p>
    <hr>
        <div class="contactField">
          <div id="result"></div>
          <label for="name"><span>Ihr Name</span>
            <input class="frm-name email required" type="text" name="name" id="name">
          </label>

          <label for="email"><span>Ihre E-Mail</span>
            <input class="frm-mail email required" type="email" name="email" id="email">
          </label>

          <label for="subject"><span>Betreff</span>
            <input class="frm-mail subject required" name="subject" id="subject">
          </label>

          <label for="message"><span>Nachricht</span>
            <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="30" class="no-value frm-message required" id="message"></textarea>
          </label>

          <label>
            <button class="submit_btn" id="submit_btn">Abschicken</button>
          </label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

jQuery

```
$("#submit_btn").click(function() {
    //get input field values
    var user_name       = $('input[name=name]').val();
    var user_email      = $('input[name=email]').val();
    var user_subject    = $('input[name=subject]').val();
    var user_message    = $('textarea[name=message]').val();

    //simple validation at client's end
    //we simply change border color to red if empty field using .css()
    var proceed = true;
    if(user_name==""){
        $('input[name=name]').css('border-color','red');
        proceed = false;
    }
    if(user_email==""){
        $('input[name=email]').css('border-color','red');
        proceed = false;
    }
    if(user_subject==""){
        $('input[name=subject]').css('border-color','red');
        proceed = false;
    }
    if(user_message=="") {  
        $('textarea[name=message]').css('border-color','red');
        proceed = false;
    }

    //everything looks good! proceed...
    if(proceed)
    {
        //data to be sent to server
        post_data = {'userName':user_name, 'userEmail':user_email, 'userSubject':user_subject, 'userMessage':user_message};

        //Ajax post data to server
        $.post('mail.php', post_data, function(response){  

            //load json data from server and output message    
            if(response.type == 'error')
            {
                output = '<div class="error">'+response.text+'</div>';
            }else{

                output = '<div class="success">'+response.text+'</div>';

                //reset values in all input fields
                $('#contact_form input').val('');
                $('#contact_form textarea').val('');
            }

            $("#result").hide().html(output).slideDown();
        }, 'json');

    }
});

//reset previously set border colors and hide all message on .keyup()
$("#contact_form input, #contact_form textarea").keyup(function() {
    $("#contact_form input, #contact_form textarea").css('border-color','');
    $("#result").slideUp();
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
    $to_Email       = "mymail.com"; //Replace with recipient email address


    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

        //exit script outputting json data
        $output = json_encode(
        array(
            'type'=>'error',
            'text' => 'Request must come from Ajax'
        ));

        die($output);
    }

    //check $_POST vars are set, exit if any missing
    if(!isset($_POST["userName"]) || !isset($_POST["userEmail"]) || !isset($_POST["userMessage"])) || !isset($_POST["userSubject"]))
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Input fields are empty!'));
        die($output);
    }

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $user_Name        = filter_var($_POST["userName"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Subject   = filter_var($_POST["userSubject"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Email       = filter_var($_POST["userEmail"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $user_Message     = filter_var($_POST["userMessage"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //additional php validation
    if(strlen($user_Name)<4) // If length is less than 4 it will throw an HTTP error.
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Ihr Name ist zu kurz.'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($user_Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) //email validation
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Das ist keine gültige E-Mail Adresse'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(strlen($user_Subject)<2) //check emtpy message
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Sie haben einen Betreff vergessen!'));
        die($output);
    }    
    if(strlen($user_Message)<5) //check emtpy message
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Sie haben Ihre Nachricht vergessen!'));
        die($output);
    }

    //proceed with PHP email.
    $headers = 'From: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

        // send mail
    $sentMail = @mail($to_Email, $user_Subject, $user_Message .'  -'.$user_Name, $headers);

    if(!$sentMail)
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Konnte Mail nicht verschicken. Wenden Sie sich an den Administrator.'));
        die($output);
    }else{
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => .$user_Name .' Vielen Dank für Ihre Nachricht.'));
        die($output);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What have you tried is my first question? Have you tried with debugger of browser, is this the response or the request data? When you return only a valid value (always success) does it work correctly? If not, its not your PHP but your call, else it is possible your PHP

Comment: the error is due to codes some elsewhere.

Comment: Tried to grab the POST by Firebug. And the POST is correct.
Live example: http://alis-schrottundmetallhandel.de/web/kontakt.html

Comment: *"But a get a error by jquery.js on line 9631"* well, what was the error?

Comment: POST http://alis-schrottundmetallhandel.de/web/mail.php
 
500 Internal Server Error 
jquery.js (Zeile 9631)
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://alis-schrottundmetallhandel.de/web/mail.php"

Comment: The error is PHP related, not js. Debug your php code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using AJAX you need to prevent the default action of clicking the submit button -

```
$("#submit_btn").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //get input field values
    ....
```

Comment: If a real submit button is used ;-)

Comment: True dat! Belt *and* suspenders when needed.

Comment: No thats not the problem. I use a simple button, no submit button. As Kevin suggested it is maybe a php bug.

Comment: If it is a PHP problem @JSNooB there should be something in your error logs.

Comment: *"True dat! Belt and suspenders when needed."* - Some like snapping both ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thx to Kevin B. Found my own copy mistakes in the php file.

The if clause had two closing brackets and a '.' in the bottom was wrong.